# NativeScript Angular text viewer links in text

Tags: nativescript

This is more of a design question. How should I handle links inside of text in NativeScript?

### Background:

I am creating a module within a larger application which acts as an 'article' viewer. I have set of predefined templates and when I get the article from backend I know which template to use for received article. It's usually some short text, an image and a button with link - like "Congrats, you received a voucher" and then a button to use it. These change often and I don't want to have to rebuild the app every time when a new request for simple page arrives.
I am mapping the server response to native script elements.

Article example:

> article = {label1: 'someText', button1: {text: 'buttonName', link:
>   '/somewhere'}}

Template example:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label [text]="article.label1" class="header1"></Label>
    <Button [text]="article.button1.text" [nsRouterLink]="article.button1.link"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

### Question

How should I manage link inside of text? (the link can be app's route, phone number, calendar...)

> article = {label: {'This is @link@'}, links: ['/someRoute']}

I figured I have these options:

- mark the link with some special character (like example above) - I would then need to parse the response which I'd like to avoid.
- display texts with links in them as a HtmlView (doesn't seem clean)
- use webview for the whole module and just get the article as html

Am I able to call angular component's method from within HtmlView or WebView?

Comment: The proper way to display clickable link inside NativeScritp View is to use HtmlView - https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_html_view_.htmlview.html , which will redirect the user to the mobile browser on tap.

Comment: Is there a way I can use router links? (navigation within app) or just to access angular component's methods, I can take it from there